# monitoring an email address

Tags: gmail, libgmail

I'm hoping for an event based way to know when I get an email.  Right now I'm using gmail but the email host isn't critical.  Do I really have to poll it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could forward the mail to a *nix host that uses .forward files, then pipe the mail to a script that handles raising the event in your program (by pinging a URL, etc.)

Here's an example in a CPanel/PHP environment: http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_pipe_an_email_to_a_PHP_script.html

Comment: cool, google app engine can do this: it receive emails *@myapp.appspotmail.com and then ping my webhook with it. so users have to forward to their own myapp email address which is okay.

Answer (score 3):

If you connect to gmail using IMAP, you should be able to use the [IDLE command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE). Gmail's IMAP server does support IDLE.

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 5465](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5465) proposes a NOTIFY extension to IMAP. It is unlikely that many servers implement it, though.

Answer (score 1):

I've had bad luck with IDLE on both GMAIL and on Dreamhost (which uses courier). Exchange does a great job with IDLE though: I see mailbox updates in less than a second.

Without good IDLE support, yes, you need to poll.